# Whonix with Remmina to Connect on RDP - Is it safe?

Tags: vpn, tor, rdp

I do not want my ISP logging any of my data, and do not trust my VPN either. Is it a safe measure to use Whonix in a VirtualBox, connecting over VPN, then using remmina to connect to an RDP? My goal is so that ISP and VPN cannot log data of RDP server to which I connect.

Basically current setup VPN -> VirtualBox with Whonix -> RDP using Remmina

Comment: Why VPN into TOR?  Can you not run the whonix gateway instance locally?

Comment: reason for connect to VPN is so ISP logs my connection to VPN not TOR, is there a better way? @DarkMatter

Answer (score 0):

If you have Whonix and install RDP on it, it's secure enough to almost everyone. Unless your government is interested in you specially, of course.

Now, if you don't trust your VPN, switch to a more trustworthy one. There are lots and lots of providers out there.

Answer (score 0):

First step is pseudo-safety, there is not much point to connect to VPN for Whonix, that's the entire purpose of the program.

Comment: Why is there no point? What's the entire purpose of what program? This answer needs a little expanding and explanation.